# Android widget for showing a regularly updated generated image, ideally with nearest neighbor scaling

Tags: android, user-interface, imageview

I'm new to Android development. I have a library here that produces LCD images that come from a device through USB. These images are small, 120x80 pixel, and are 1-bit. I want to show these images on the UI.

All documents I've found explain how to show bitmaps from image files (PNG etc.) or how to show them from an app's resources. I did find out that I can add an `ImageView` to the UI. Then, for each incoming 120x80 pixel image, create a `Bitmap` instance, fill it with pixels, and assign it to the `ImageView`. However, I do not know if this yields the best performance here.

It is also important to keep in mind that nearest neighbor scaling must be used here. Bilinear filtering with such a small image produces a result that is too blurry.

From my experience with other languages, it seems wasteful to create a `Bitmap` instance for each incoming image. But perhaps I am wrong here.

Suggestions?

Comment: Draw your pixels to a `Canvas`, perhaps in `onDraw()` of a custom `View` that renders that `Canvas` to the screen.

Comment: OK, this works. But when I use `drawBitmap()`, it is filtered. Any way to disable that to get nearest neighbour scaling?

Comment: My apologies. I was thinking that the `Canvas` API had a better API for this scenario than it actually appears to. If you are creating a `Bitmap`, you might as well then continue to use `ImageView`. Note that you can reuse a `Bitmap` instance (e.g., `eraseColor()`, then set your pixels as desired). So, you might flip between two `Bitmap` instances: the one presently being rendered in the `ImageView` and the one that you are preparing for the next frame. When that `Bitmap` is ready, hand it to the `ImageView` and use the previous `Bitmap` for the next frame.